# Openocd: Write a value to flash address

Tags: c, arm, gdb, cortex-m, openocd

I want to write a specific value to an address in flash using openocd.
The address is `0x0003FFF0`. ANd the value I want to write to it is `0xFFFFC000`.

To erase that address I used:
`flash erase_address 0x0003FFF0 2048`

but got an error message `address range 0x0003fff0 .. 0x0003ffff is not sector-aligned`

To fix this I ran `flash info 0` to find the address to start from and then ran `flash erase_address 0x38000 2048` and this worked.

Finally to write the value to flash I tried:

`reset halt`

`mww 0x0003FFF0 0xFFFFC000`

but got this error:

`SWD ack not OK: 4 FAULT`
`SWD IDCODE 0x2ba01477`

Comment: Could you show the code before `mww`?

Comment: @RingØ Updated now, just a `reset halt`

Comment: this is a microcontroller and very specific to the chip (cortex-m3 is not the chip, not really related at all other than a blob that the debugger communicates through to get at the chip specific peripheral).   so first off there is no reason to expect flashing from openocd to work, once we went from parallel to serial flashes that all ended (chip specific, where it wasnt necessarily before).  so what chip are you using, and what openocd version and what command line and/or openocd script are you using to gain access?

Comment: Few µC will allow direct writes to flash with `mww`. That is why openOCD has special flash write commands.

Answer (score 0):

That error message (assuming it's accurate) indicates that the debug port on the chip (the slave for the SWD connection) has detected an error. This might be a parity error on the SWD, a read polling mismatch or an AHB error response. See [table 2.10 here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0314h/Chdhbffe.html). Without digging into which of these openOCD can handle, its hard to tell. This is only a symptom of your problem though - it is quite likely that writes directly to the flash are not supported in your chip (or at least not without some preamble to prepare the flash controller)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "just" write any value to flash memory. In (almost?) all cases you have to follow a very specific procedure to actually write something there (like set this bit, wait for some other bit, write the address to this register, write the value to that register, set another bit, wait for "done" bit, repeat...). That's why the thing you are trying to do just won't work unless you implement this particular procedure with more `mww` (and `mmw` and `mdw`, or variants which use 16-bits of 8-bits, as sometimes you may write only 2 bytes at once, not all 4) commands before the actual write.